# Thymeleaf switch or if для выбора класса

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

Как через `switch` или `if` добавить класс?

```
<tbody>
        <tr th:each="book:${books}">
            <td wk:text="${book.name}"></td>
            <td wk:text="${book.author}"></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

Есть переменная `${book.state.name()}`, которая содержит `NEW`, `SOLD`, `BACK`. Нужно в зависимости от ее значения тегу `<tr>` добавить определенный класс. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю, как-то на подобии

```
<tr th:each="book:${books}" th:class=
"${book.state.name eq 'NEW'} ? 'green'
: (${book.state.name eq 'SOLD'} ? 'yellow' 
: 'red')">
```

Но я не запускал, здесь можно по операторам более детально посмотреть
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standarddialect5minutes.html